# Save values of JS object as Markup

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to save markup on a JS object to be retrieved later?

Why?

Here lies my problem, if a description is too long, I'd like to be able to break it into separate chunks, perhaps different HTML tags, as opposed to having the entire text in one long chain of words

ie: after looping through object...

```
 <div>{markup.description}</div>
```

the above would give me all the description data, but I wouldn't able to massage it (break into bold, italic, headings, or spans.) for a better UI.

So the end result that I'm trying to learn here is how to produce something like:

```
const markup = [
       {
         name: "<h1>Joe Doe<h1/>",
         food: "<p>pizza<p/>",
         description: "<h1>super long description<h2><p>bla bla 
         bla</p>"   
       }
    ]
```

I tried template literals but no dice.

I know I could separate chunks of text by adding more keys in the object, but that feels redundant because it is all a description, besides I still wouldn't be able to apply any styles (add a class) for words that need attention in the middle of the text.

Comment: vue... react... angular...is calling you... just kidding may not yet

Comment: I am using React. Just didn't mention because I thought this was broader (?). How would this work w/ React?

Comment: oh okay good lol

Comment: What are your thoughts to my question?

Comment: Depending on how long these really are, just put them in separate html files... and if they're not that long and you still want to put them in your code then make them their own react component

Comment: They're distinct  elements of a description so breaking it into separate chunks of text with appropriate keys on the object is absolutely not redundant. Surely the very fact that you want to break up this information into chunks for display to the end user indicates that?

Comment: So what if 50 characters inside the string, I'd like to bold a specific word and then another one 100 characters later, or add classes for style? That doesn't sound optimal.

Comment: If every item has a name, food and description property then it makes sense to structure your data, assuming you have control over it, to suit the output. If you want certain words within your description to be bold then by all means mark them up, but as a general rule you should avoid markup in your raw data. What happens if you want to display the same data somewhere else in your application?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet That's a very valid point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can always make the properties functions.

```js
const markup = [{
  name: () => "<h1>Joe Doe<h1/>",
  food: () => "<p>pizza<p/>",
  description: () => "<h1>super long description<h2><p>bla bla bla</p>"
}]

function renderMarkup(item) {
  let markup = ''
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    markup += value()
  });
  return markup
}

$('.markup').html(renderMarkup(markup[0]))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="markup"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Do you mind showing me how the function would be written based on my example? I'm confused what goes where. I'm still a newbie....

Comment: What are you gaining out of making the properties functions?

Comment: I am used to `jsx` and `react` but I guess you are right and in this particular example making the property a function is not really necessary.

Comment: `renderMarkup` is still valid though

Comment: @NullisTrue You should absolutely not be doing this if you're using React.

Comment: @JLRishe, that's why I omitted the react portion. I was interested to learn for uses cases where libraries and/or frameworks aren't present. After all, not every project can be a green field.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React and have JSX available, you can store JSX fragments in a variable and then reference them when you render. However, the markup you've written is very malformed. You have closing tags with the slash in the wrong place and you have an `h1` matched up with an `h2`. JSX markup has to be valid, and each fragment has to be enclosed in a tag that contains the whole fragment.

[This works](https://codesandbox.io/s/9z4jzrk7vo):

```
const markup = [
  {
    name: <h1>Joe Doe</h1>,
    food: <p>pizza</p>,
    description: <div><h1>super long description</h1><p>bla bla bla</p></div>
  },
  {
    name: <h1>Janet Doe</h1>,
    food: <p>chicken</p>,
    description: <div><h1>yet another super long description</h1><p>bla bla bla</p></div>
  }
];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    { markup.map(r => [r.name, r.food, r.description]) }
  </div>
);
```